# What's the term for the bullied kid who delivers bread and sandwiches to the bullies?

Tags: terminology

I think it's a designated term for this kind of character. Usually they use their own money to purchase foods during lunch in a school setting for the bullies.

Comment: I think this question is a better fit for  https://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

[Bread Shuttles](https://www.google.com/search?q=bread+shuttle). Korean. Not Japanese.

> 빵셔틀
>
> [ppang-syeoteul]
> Term literally meaning ‘bread shuttle.’ Usually used at school, where one student is picked on and/or bullied to do the errands for people who are in a stronger position than they are.

https://www.koreabang.com/glossary

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of this in *Sumire 16-sai!!*, chapter 1:

[image: ！！この人....私をパシリにする為に....]

The word is [パシリ](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%91%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA) (translates to "gofer" in English):

> Person who is made to do things or go get things for someone else; person who runs errands; gofer​ (see also [使いっ走り](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E8%B5%B0%E3%82%8A))